# Can I consistently open a file in python?

Tags: python, file

I find each time I open a file and read its content, it automatically close. So next time I have to open that file again to read it. I know this may be a good idea to reduce memory usage. But I need to consistently open a file due to my current task.

How should I do it?

This is my current way of reading a file

```
f = open('some_file', 'rU')
f.read()
```

Comment: It will only close when your script finishes or you call `f.close()`

Comment: or if you open inside a method upon exit from your method file descriptor is closed

Comment: @sshashank124, I'm using my terminal to do this, if I read the 'f' object once, the next time I read it, I'll get an empty string. Why that happened if it wasn't closed?

Comment: @Zen: Because the file maintains a current position. Calling `read` with no argument reads to the end, where it will remain, so calling `read` again reads from the current position (the end) to the end, aka nothing. If you want to go back to the start, you can use `f.seek(0)`.

Comment: If you're going to read the whole thing into memory at once, why not just save the contents? `text = f.read()`. Now you don't have to keep calling `read` or keep the file open.

Comment: @user2357112, I want to know the consistently status of this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you do `f.read()`, the file doesn't *close*. In fact, it doesn't close unless you explicitly call `f.close()` or you use it in a with block like this:

```
with open('some_file') as f:
     ...
```

In which case, the file will be closed for you when the with block ends. It will also tend to be closed in any case when the file object has no more variables associated with it (ie, when `f` falls out of scope or gets reassigned), but this isn't guaranteed behaviour. If none of these things happen, the file *is* kept open.

The problem you are most likely seeing is that calling `read` again will get you an empty string. This doesn't happen because the file is *closed* - reading from a closed file gives you an error. Rather, files keep track of where you have read up to, so that if you only read part of it, you can then request the *next* part and it will start at the right place. To set it back to read from the start of the file again again, you can use the `seek` method:

```
with open('some_file') as f:
   contents1 = f.read()
   f.seek(0)
   contents2 = f.read()
```

will give you contents1 and contents2 both containing the full contents of the file, rather than contents2 being empty. However, you probably don't want to do this unless the file could have changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your file will consisently open or be consistently open, you need to be closing files or `seek` to `0`.

```
while True:
    f = open(...) 
    x = f.read() 
    print x
    f.close()
```

or

```
f = open(...) 
while True:
    x = f.read() 
    print x
    f.seek(0)
```

...unless you are going to write a one-liner, which will close automatically.

```
print open('some_file', 'rU').read()
```

This avoids any limit on the number of open files.

Additional thought: You can also use `for line in open(...): pass`, again as long as you remember to get to the beginning of the file one way or another.